# Footer not appearing on pages with programmatically added content

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I have a base document with sections created by programmatically inserting from a separate template document. The insertion is fine, but the footer isn't appearing on any extra pages created as a result of the insertion, i.e. the first page has a footer, but page two (created by inserting content) does not. If the original document has a two pages then it will render with a footer on the first two pages, but not the third.

Is there a way I can force the footer to render on all of the pages I have created?

Comment: This ended up being a problem to do with which footer is was using. For some reason some of the pages are using the footer "for each page" and the pages I were inserting were using the footer "for every other page". I solved my issue by putting the same footer in each of those categories (tick the box, set the footer then untick the box and set the footer again). It was a pretty hacky solution but I couldn't find any other way around it.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of Headers/Footers in a Section e.g.

1. Header/Footer for First page,
2. Primary Header/Footer which can also be used for Odd numbered pages and
3. Header/Footer for Even numbered pages.

So, if you want to keep same Header/Footer across all pages in Word document, you can first clear all Headers/Footers (see Section.HeadersFooters.Clear() method) from all Sections in Document and then build/assign a single Primary Header/Footer to the first Section.

You might also want to turn off/on 'Different First Page' and 'Different Odd & Even Pages' options using 'Section.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter' and 'Section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter' properties.

Also, using Aspose.Words, you can programmatically [control How Headers and Footers should appear](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Controlling+How+Header+and+Footers+Appear) during Joining and Appending Documents.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.